# Convergence test of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\ln^n(\frac{1}{n})} $

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to test for convergence and absolute convergence this sum: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\ln^n(\frac{1}{n})} $.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is $\ln^n$ the $n$th power or the $n$th iterated logarithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac1{\ln^n\left(\frac1n\right)}=\frac1{\bigl(-\ln(n)\bigr)^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln^n(n)}.$

Comment: And how does this help to determine the absolute convergence?

Comment: It doesn't, but it's useful to prove that it converges.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that for $n>e^2$,

$$\left|\frac{1}{\log^n(1/n)}\right|\le \frac1{2^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac1{\ln^n\left(\frac1n\right)}=\frac1{\bigl(-\ln(n)\bigr)^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln^n(n)}$$

and by Cauchy condensation test we have

$$\sum \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln^n(n)}\right|\le \sum \frac{2^n}{(\ln (2^n))^{2^n}}=\sum \frac{2^n}{n^{2^n}(\ln 2)^{2^n}}$$